# Starting BroadleafCommerce-develop-5.2.x

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

How can I start BroadleafCommerce-develop-5.2.x application. How to deploy on Tomcat would be more helpful. I am able to start the Demo site- Admin, Site and API.

Answer (score 2):

When building the app you can change the packaging type in your site and admin pom.xml to `war` instead of `jar` and then drop that in a tomcat instance. Additional documentation can be found here https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/tomcat